# Select all users that have commented post in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am having a trouble with LINQ query for sort of a complicated selection.

I am trying to create simply social network, where user can post posts and other users can comment on them.
For some statistic I want to find out who are the user who left comments on all posts of currently logged on user.

This are the tasks I am trying to preform:

- Find currently logged on user.
- Get all other registered user (except currently logged on).
- Get all comments on all posts that currently logged on user has.
- Since every comment has UserId which presents ID of a user who has left the comment, I want to compare this UserIds with all other registered users and get list of users who were commenting to currently logged on user.

It sound bit complicated, but it is not actually.

This is my code:

```
public ActionResult ListAllUsersThatCommentedPostsToCurrentUser()
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    //Get ID from current user
    var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
    var comments = new List<Comment>();

    if (user != null)
    {
        //Get all posts of current user
        var postsOfCurrentUser = db.Posts.Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id).ToList();

        foreach (var post in postsOfCurrentUser)
        {
            //Get all comments on posts which belong to current user
            comments = db.Comments.Where(x => x.PostId == post.PostId).ToList();
        }
    }
    var usersThatCommentedPosts = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    if (comments != null)
    {
        //Get all user except current one
        var otherUsers = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id != currentUserId).ToList();
        foreach(var comment in comments)
        {
            //Filter all users except current one according to UserIds in Comment list
            usersThatCommentedPosts = otherUsers.Where(u => u.Id == comment.UserId).ToList();
        }
    }

    return View(usersThatCommentedPosts);
}
```

The problem is in this line:

```
usersThatCommentedPosts = otherUsers.Where(u => u.Id == comment.UserId).ToList();
```

I always get last user how left the comment to current user, instead of list of all users who have left comments.
I guess the problem is in foreach loop, but I have a mess in my head and no idea how can I implement this in a different and more efficient way.
As well, if somebody see something that can be refactored comments are more than welcome, because I have feeling that I have made unnecessary mess here.

Comment: `Where(u => u.Id == comment.UserId)` will probably return single item and not full list

Comment: @Rahul Yes it does, but I am not sure how to accomplish returning of all of them. :/

Comment: do you know if you have a foreign key relationship between Users and Comments?  does your `comment` object has a `Users` property?

Answer (score 4):

you're replacing `usersThatCommentedPosts` every iteration of that loop.  If you want to append to the loop, use `AddRange`

```
var users = otherUsers.Where(u => u.Id == comment.UserId).ToList();
usersThatCommentedPosts.AddRange(users );
```

---

or better yet, do a join in a proper query.  (this way you don't have db queries in a loop)

```
var userQry =
    from post in db.Posts
    join comment in db.Comments on post.PostId equals comment.PostId
    join otherUser in db.Users on comment.UserId equals otherUser.Id
    where post.UserId == currentUserId
    where otherUser.Id != currentUserId
    select otherUser;

var users = userQry.ToList();
```

Comment: @nemo_87  you can probably replace that entire function with the join query I've posted.  You'd do well to study up SQL and Linq so that you can understand how that and queries like it work.   If you're working on a project that interacts with the DB, it will help you out a lot